# Question about loading reviews from a text API using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So I'm trying to load these reviews from a text API I've been given onto a webpage, here are two as an example.

```
[{"id":"1","product_id":"scooter","nickname":"James","review":"I'm impressed with the result","rating":"5"},{"id":"2","product_id":"scooter","nickname":"Jerry","review":"Its rubbish","rating":"1"}]
```

There are about 13 in total. To load them into my HTML document, I'm trying to use an ajax function with a loop, then adding the corresponding values into the html file with an append function. I know the javascript code below doesn't work because as none of the reviews have specific identifiers, the code I included pastes all of the review values in every h4 or p item in the html document every time.

My question is how do I fetch the nickname and review items from the API so that they only appear once each on my html document?

Example of where I want 2 reviews to load. The reviewer name in the h4 tag and the review itself within the p tag.

```
<div id="productreviews">

<img id="reviewimg1" src="reviewicon1.jpg" alt="An image of a vehicle, a stock 
    user review image.">
    <h3 class="idfont" id="reviewcaption1">Good God!!</h3>
    <h4 class="idfont idposition" id="reviewuser1"></h4>
    <p class="maintext" id="reviewmain1"></p>

<img id="reviewimg2" src="reviewicon1.jpg" alt="An image of a vehicle, a stock 
    user review image.">
    <h3 class="idfont" id="reviewcaption2">Great</h3>
    <h4 class="idfont idposition" id="reviewuser2"></h4>
    <p class="maintext" id="reviewmain2"></p>
</div>
```

Here is my current Javascript

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    var list = $("#productreviews").find('h4');
list.empty();
var promise = $.ajax('API_link_goes_here');
promise.done(function(data) {
    for(idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
     list.append('<dd>' + data[idx].nickname + '</dd>');
    }
});
    var list2 = $("#productreviews").find('p');
list2.empty();
var promise = $.ajax('API_link_goes_here');
promise.done(function(data) {
    for(idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
     list2.append('<dd>' + data[idx].review + '</dd>');
    }
});
```

Comment: once your promises are done, you should be doing something with your data.  Like injecting it into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of how I tend to accomplish something like this;

1. Make an invisible review HTML template
2. retrieve and parse the data *skipped for snippet functionality*
3. process the data by doing the following for each item;

   -cloning the template.

   -filling in the clone.

   -adding the clone to a placeholder

```js
var dataString = '[{"id":"1","product_id":"scooter","nickname":"James","review":"Im impressed with the result ","rating ":"5 "},{"id ":"2 ","product_id ":"scooter ","nickname":"Jerry ","review":"Its rubbish ","rating ":"1 "}]';

$(function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(dataString);
  var $template = $("#template");
  //var promise = $.ajax('API_link_goes_here').
  //promise.done(function(data) {
  for (idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
    var item = $template.clone();
    item.find(".user").text(data[idx].nickname); //set the nickname
    item.find(".maintext").text(data[idx].review); //set the review text
    item.show(); //toggle the visibility cause the template was hidden
    $("#reviews").append(item);
  }
  //});
});
```

```css
#reviews .reviewWrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='template' class='reviewWrapper' style='display:none'>
  <img src="reviewicon1.jpg" alt="An image of a vehicle, a stock 
    user review image.">
  <h3 class="idfont caption">Great</h3>
  <h4 class="idfont idposition user"></h4>
  <p class="maintext"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <div id='reviews'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I am required to call the review data from the API link and not locally as you have done in the variable datastring.

Comment: sure, I left your promise commented out.  I assumed it was functional and the DOM injection was where the hangup was.

uncommenting the promise call to your API and getting rid of `var data` should function as you expect.